# Navigation Bar Title truncated

Tags: swift2, uinavigationbar, xcode7

I have a navigation bar title that gets truncated if too long - based on the following code, how could the issue be fixed so that the title is displayed on 2 lines at runtime?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    title = checklist.name

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CollegiateHeavyOutline", size: 23.0)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.init(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 112.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)]

}
```

The screenshot below show the title with text size 17 (uses 2 lines - nice!)
[image]

But the following is not so nice and the title should read 'But this one is cut off with size 18 and over
[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Is that what are you looking for?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "CollegiateHeavyOutline", size: 23.0)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 112.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    titleLabel.text = checklist.name
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

Comment: I am gonna give it a try!

Comment: Nope...My title is still cut off with the 3 dots (...). Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, actually, it only goes on 2 lines when the text size is under 18.0; if I set the size to 19 and above, the title gets cut off again...

Comment: Can you add the screenshot to your question please?

Comment: I added 2 screenshots to my question

Comment: Ok. I believe text view height with font over 18 is bigger than navigation bar height, therefor it's get back to 1 line and crop the end. How would you like it to look like?

Comment: Well, I guess a max size of 18 or 19 would be good, still on 2 lines